# What's the best way to write a function that conditionally searches for data tracked each week, starting at a specific point and ending at today

Tags: python, datetime, iteration

Let's say there's a list of dates in string and M/D/Y format:

```
li = ['2021-03-25', '021-03-28', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-03', '2021-04-06', '2021-04-09', '2021-04-14', '2021-04-19']
```

And say we wanted to make a DataFrame with columns ['weekOf', 'count'] that counts how many of these dates belong to a particular week starting with an input date. Also, this is a function so the first monday will be an input. I know making the first row would look something like this:

```
li1 = []
        li1.append({'weekOf': (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                    'count' : len([x for x in li if (datetime.datetime.strptime(since, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)) 
                                    > x > datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d')])
                               })
```

but how would one chain this so that it keeps making new rows until it ends with today's date? For instance:

```
 li1 = []
 if datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') < datetime.date.now:
       li1.append({'weekOf': (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                    'count' : len([x for x in li if (datetime.datetime.strptime(since, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)) 
                                    > x > datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d')])
                               })
       if (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days = 7) < datetime.date.now:
               li1.append({'weekOf': (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                    'count' : len([x for x in li if (datetime.datetime.strptime(since, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)) 
                                    > x > datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d')])
                               })
               if (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days = 14) < datetime.date.now:
                      li1.append({'weekOf': (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                    'count' : len([x for x in li if (datetime.datetime.strptime(since, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=7)) 
                                    > x > datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d')])
                               })
```

...etc

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct output is supposed to be, but it's either a for loop or a while loop. Or possibly the equivalent list comprehension. You definitely don't want to repeat code in multiple if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this done.

```
li1 = []
    #calculates how many weeks the for loop should run based on how many weeks there are from the start date
    end = math.floor((datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.min.time()) - 
                     (datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d'))).days/7)
    counter = 0
    while counter <= end:
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days = 7 * counter)
        li1.append({'weekOf': (start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
                                'count' : len([x for x in li if (start + datetime.timedelta(days= 7)) 
                                > x >= (start)])
                           })
        counter += 1

    #Creates dataframe from list of dictionaries
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(li1, columns = ['weekOf', 'count'])
    
    return df1
```